# Scrolling with jQuery when scrolling is disabled on CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to scroll the page using a jQuery animation but the scrolling is disabled in the CSS and it doesn't allow the animation to take place:

```
$('html, body').css({
    'overflow': 'hidden',
    'height': '100%'
});


$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 939
}, 2500);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AKPHB/1/

Comment: It works everywhere except webkit-based browsers. Sure it's not an answer, just interesting note.

Comment: @Tommi "everywhere" — really?

Comment: I found a solution that works for me in Chrome & IE 10

Comment: I tried in Opera 12.16; IE10 in 10 && 9 mode, latest FF, Chrome and Safari (Windows). It doesn't work in Chrome and Safari (both webkit-based)

Comment: @Tommi Im looking for a cross browser solution anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set overflow:hidden, the scroll event doesn’t happen. So you can’t trigger it using the animation either. And really, what’s the point of animating a scroll if the user can’t scroll anyway :p

One solution is to wrap the content in another container and animate the container instead, like this:

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AKPHB/10/**

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="text">text</div>
    <div class="text">text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content{position:relative}
```

And the Javascript:

```
$('#content').animate({ top: -939 });
```

Comment: Interesting to see that you used the property `top` instead of `scrollTop` for the animation. I was trying it with a container also but it seems it doesn't work with `scrollTop`. Thanks!

Comment: @alvaro there’s no magic there. The scroll is disabled and so is the "scrollTop" animation property since it triggers the scroll itself.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest using `margin-top` instead. The effect to the user will be the same, since there's no scrollbar:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AKPHB/5/)

```
$('html, body').animate({
    "margin-top": -100,
    "height": "+=200"     // Fix height to show additional content   
}, 2500);
```

Comment: It seems more kind of a trick than a proper way to do it. Also, is not that smooth compare with the desired result: http://jsfiddle.net/AKPHB/4/

Comment: Im sure there should be a way. Just look at this site with overflow hidden in its body: http://onlinedepartment.nl/about-us/#designprinciples